# Get span from iframe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have `gindex.html`, content is JavaScript game, this game give me the result in:

```
<span id="success"></span>
```

Now I included `gindex.html` in `index.html` using `iframe` this code:

```
document.getElementById('quiz').innerHTML = '<h4 id="qnr">&#9675;  question number.'+ (nquiz + 1) +'</h4><iframe id="iframei2" src="indexg.html"></iframe><button id="nextq" onclick="obTrivia.sQuiz(\'next\')">next</button>';
```

and import (get) the success by:

```
var mygrade = document.getElementById("iframei2").contentWindow.document.getElementById("success");
```

then I used `if` to know (Right or Wrong):

```
if (mygrade >= 7) {
    nia++;  // Wrong
}else if (mygrade < 7) {
    nca++; // Right
}
```

the problem is the result of `if` is "Right" every time?!

Comment: `mygrade` is an DOM element and you are comparing it to a number

Comment: You need to use something like `if (parseInt(mygrade.innerText) >= 7)`

Comment: Take the good habit to debug a bit before posting, like: check what is inside your variables so that you are sure of what you actually do.

Comment: epascarello, Thank you, please what is the solution.
Barmar, i tested your code but not work with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the text of the span and compare that:

```
if (mygrade.innerText != "" && parseInt(mygrade.innerText, 10) >= 7)
```

Comment: Thank you, but not work with me, before the code give me Right every time, but now not give me anything?

Comment: maybe the problem is "if" get the "span" content before play the game, how i can let if get the "success" after play?

Comment: Then the problem is with setting `mygrade`. Make sure you don't set it until the iframe is loaded.